# Regular Expression won't work in bash, works in other tools

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following string:

```
Started GET "/stuff/search?search_string=Actin&organism_id=9&advanced_design=false&user_ip=172.16.0.1&filter=" for 172.16.0.4 at 2015-06-30 13:58:26 +0200
  Parameters: {"search_string"=>"Actin", "organism_id"=>"9", "advanced_design"=>"false", "user_ip"=>"172.16.0.1", "filter"=>""}
Started GET "/stuff/search?search_string=NM_001101&organism_id=9&advanced_design=false&user_ip=172.16.0.1&filter=" for 172.16.0.4 at 2015-06-30 14:00:39 +0200
  Parameters: {"search_string"=>"NM_001101", "organism_id"=>"9", "advanced_design"=>"false", "user_ip"=>"172.16.0.1", "filter"=>""}
Started GET "/stuff/search?search_string=ENST00000331789&organism_id=9&advanced_design=false&user_ip=172.16.0.1&filter=" for 172.16.0.4 at 2015-06-30 14:00:49 +0200
  Parameters: {"search_string"=>"ENST00000331789", "organism_id"=>"9", "advanced_design"=>"false", "user_ip"=>"172.16.0.1", "filter"=>""}
```

and I want to extract the value of the "search_string" key. I need to do this in a bash script. For this I have came up with the following regular expression:

```
"\{(\"search_string\"\=\>\")([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)(.*?)\}"
```

I have tested this on multiple online regular expression testers, like rubular or regex101.com and it works fine there. However, in bash, the regex does not match the text.

Here is my script (i have cut off the text for this question, but normally the text in a file which i am grep-ing):

```
#!/bin/bash
regex="\{(\"search_string\"\=\>\")([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)(.*?)\}"
string='{"search_string"=>"NM_001101"}'
if [[ $string =~ $regex ]]
then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "not OK"
fi

filename="/some/path/search.txt"
if [ -f "$filename" ]
then
    result=$(grep -F "$regex" "$filename")
    echo "$result"
else
    echo "$filename is not a file or it does not exist"
fi
```

In this case, the script returns "`not OK`".

Obviously, the script is not ready yet as I am stuck with this regular expression. What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: One thing you're doing wrong is assuming that all regular expression engines are the same! Regex101 has a list of languages it supports, your mileage will almost certainly vary with other languages. I notice that you're using `grep -F` which matches using fixed strings - this is certainly wrong. Perhaps you'd be better off using `-P` (Perl mode) if your version of grep supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just escape all the backslashes other than the one before double quotes one more time.

```
regex="\\{\"search_string\"=>\"[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+(.*?)\\}"
string='{"search_string"=>"NM_001101"}'
echo $regex
if [[ $string =~ $regex ]]
then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "not OK"
fi
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/D3MHoc)

Answer (score 1):

This regex works in `awk`, so you could make some modifications to your script and use `awk` for the matching. `awk` readlines lines from stdin or every line of a file by default, and regex are enclosed like "//", commands are enclosed like "{}". Here I echoed your example, piped the stdin to `awk` and used the command "print ok" to test if the regex was matched. I think you can take this piece of code to make your script work the way you want in bash.

```
~$ echo '{"search_string"=>"NM_001101"}' | awk '/\{(\"search_string\"\=\>\")([a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]+)(.*?)\}/{print "ok"}'
ok
```

Comment: It does not seem to work for me ... I get no "ok" after executing it